# How do you split an Array of Strings by its elements

Tags: java

How is it possible to split the String[] bookings by its elements. For example

```
Tokens[0] = 8  
Tokens[1] = 2  
Tokens[2] = Nobbly, Greg  
Tokens[3] = Nobbly, Jo-Anne  
Tokens[4] = 1  
Tokens[5] = Lee, Sook


public static String[] BookingList()
      {
        String[] bookings = new String[]{"8","2","Nobbly, Greg","Nobbly, Jo-Anne","1","Lee, Sook","3","Lukas, Stephie","Lukas, Cambridge","Lukas, Ogden"}; 
        String[] tokens = new String[bookings.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < bookings.length; i++)
        {
          tokens = bookings[i].trim().split(",");
        }
        return tokens;
      }
```

Comment: Do you mean access those elements individually? For instance, 8, 2, etc.?

Comment: can you be more specific on your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

The elements are there already in the String array `bookings` . You can check that by simply printing them:

```
String[] bookings = new String[]{"8","2","Nobbly, Greg","Nobbly, Jo-Anne","1","Lee, Sook","3","Lukas, Stephie","Lukas, Cambridge","Lukas, Ogden"};
for(String booking: bookings) {
    System.out.println(booking);
}
```

which prints:

`8
2
Nobbly, Greg
Nobbly, Jo-Anne
1
Lee, Sook
3
Lukas, Stephie
Lukas, Cambridge
Lukas, Ogden`

You can make `tokens` refer to `bookings` by writing:

```
String[] tokens = bookings;
```

The point to note is now both `tokens` and `bookings` refer to same array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use streaming api (for better performance) and split(regex)

```
String[] bookings = new String[]{"8", "2", "Nobbly, Greg", "Nobbly, Jo-Anne", "1", "Lee, Sook", "3", "Lukas, Stephie", "Lukas, Cambridge", "Lukas, Ogden"};
ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
Arrays.asList(bookings).forEach((String booking) -> {
    tokens.addAll(Arrays.asList(booking.split("\\s*,\\s*")));      //split booking into array and add as token in 'tokens'
});
System.out.println(tokens);
```